# how to show dotst with preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a php array like this:

```
.

..

thumb_imageA.jpg

thumb_imageB.jpg

imageA.jpg

ImageB.jpg
```

I want to skip the double dots, the single dot and everyting that start with thumb_

I have this:

```
foreach ($dirArray as $file) {
        if (!preg_match('#(^thumb_|^.)#', $file)) {
            print '<li>'.$file.'</li>';
        } etc. etc. etc.
```

It gives me a empty array
if I do this:

```
        if (!preg_match('#(^thumb_)#', $file)) {
```

then I get a array without the thumb_ but still I see the single and double dot.

How can I filter out those dots?

Comment: `if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && strpos('thumb_', $file) === false) {}`

Comment: `.` is a special character in a regex pattern that means "all characters except newlines", to obtain a literal dot, you need to escape it with a backslash. Note: you can make your pattern shorter like this: `#thumb_|\.#A`